# Can I only review 10 questions in a community evaluation?

Tags: support, site-evaluation

Yesterday several Stack Exchange sites I visit began a community evaluation. I reviewed 10 questions and answers on each of two sites, [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and [IT Security](http://security.stackexchange.com). Today, when I returned, I see that I have completed 10 reviews, but am not allowed to proceed further.

[image]

Am I only able to review 10 questions during the entire evaluation period?

Comment: I think it's just 10 posts total. As in, everyone evaluates the same 10 posts and then that's it.

Comment: Damn, that means it's going to take 25 years to get the Steward badge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, 10 questions is the whole evaluation. There'll be one every three months (on graduate sites), so it might take a while for that shiny Steward badge.

Comment: Good point about the badge. Gonna have to think about that one.

Comment: @AnnaLear I, for one, think it's perfectly appropriate for anyone who completes a quarter century of reviews to get a shiny gold badge. :)

Comment: Gold badge? In 25 years, I want Stack Exchange to host my retirement party.